# Orthogonal decomposition of a Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Then, if $M$ is a closed subspace, then I know that $H= M + M^{\star}$, where $M^{\star}$ is the orthogonal complement.

If $M$ is not closed, however, I can consider its closure $\overline M $ and its orthogonal complement $\overline M ^{\star}$ so that $H = \overline M + \overline M ^{\star}$.

But,  since orthogonal complements are always closed it seems to me that $\overline M ^{\star} = M ^{\star}$. But, is it so?

Comment: In fact, for any subset $S$ of $H$, we have $$S^*=\overline{\operatorname{span}S}^*.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $M \subset \overline{M}$ we get $(\overline{M})^* \subset M^*$.

Next, let $x \in M^*$ and let $y \in \overline{M}$. Pick some $y_n \in M$ such that $y_n \to y$.

Then 
$$0=<x_n,y> \to <x,y>$$
Therefore 
$$<x,y>=0$$

This shows that $x \in (\overline{M})^*$. Therefore $M^*  \subset (\overline{M})^*$.