# Alternative Proofs: Closed proper subspace of Hilbert space has non-empty orthogonal complement

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, alternative-proof, orthogonality

Let $(H,\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a Hilbert space. I am asking for people to present any short/basic/fundamental proofs they know of the following theorem.

> **Theorem 1:** Let $V \subseteq H$ be a closed, proper vector subspace of $H$. Then $V^\perp$ contains a non-zero vector.

Theorem 1 follows pretty easily as a corollary of either of the following theorems.

> **Theorem 2:** A vector subspace $U$ of $H$ is dense if and only if $U^\perp$ is trivial.

> **Notes on Theorem 2:** The proof may be found [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2021/REUPapers/Adler.pdf), requiring many pages of prior results. These results include $U^\perp = (\overline{U})^\perp$ and $(U^\perp)^\perp = \overline{U}$ for vector subspaces $U$ of $H$, which in turn require the "Hilbert projection theorem" and the continuity of the inner product.

> **Theorem 3:** $H = U \oplus U^\perp$ for any closed vector subspace $U$ of $H$.

> **Notes on Theorem 3:** A proof of this may be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Direct_Sum_of_Subspace_and_Orthocomplement). I believe this proof requires less machinery than the proof of Theorem 2. In particular, only the construction of the orthogonal projection and some basic properties of the projection are required.

Allow me to explain my thoughts a bit further. Theorem 2 and 3 are definitely not *long* proofs which make use of important, fundamental facts about orthogonality in Hilbert space. However, Theorem 2 and 3 seem to be much stronger results than Theorem 1. I have a gut feeling that Theorem 1 may be proven without having to resort to the "machinery" required for Theorem 2 or 3 (if you could really call it machinery). I guess another way to put it is that I believe there should be much more basic proofs of Theorem 1.

However, I have not been able to make progress on such a proof myself. If I were to guess, a proof by contradiction making clever use of the continuity of the inner product might work. But, again, I've had no such success. Please feel free to drop your proof approaches below or any reasoning as to why you think Theorem 2 or 3 are the shortest / most fundamental methods.

I hope this post allows for a better understanding for the true difficulty or simplicity of Theorem 1. So, although this is not strictly what I am looking for, also feel free to drop any super sleek proofs of Theorem 1 that use really heavy machinery ahaha Maybe such proofs will enlighten why Theorem 1 cannot be proven in a more fundamental manner. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove it without heavy machinery, but a bit of computation, using distance-minimising sequences.

Suppose $V \le H$ is closed and proper. Choose any point $x_0 \in H \setminus V$. Let
$$r = \inf_{x \in V} \|x - x_0\| > 0,$$
since $V$ is closed. Suppose $(x_n)_{n \ge 1} \in V$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n - x_0\| = r$. I claim that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy.

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Let
$$\delta = \sqrt{r^2 + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}} - r > 0.$$
Since $\|x_n - x_0\| \to r$, there exists some $N$ such that
$$n \ge N \implies r \le \|x_n - x_0\| < r + \delta = \sqrt{r^2 + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}}.$$

Suppose $m, n \ge N$. Parallelogram law states that:
$$\|(x_m - x_0) - (x_n - x_0)\|^2 + \|(x_m - x_0) + (x_n - x_0)\|^2 = 2\|x_m - x_0\|^2 + 2\|x_n - x_0\|^2,$$
or equivalently,
$$\|x_m - x_n\|^2 = 2\|x_m - x_0\|^2 + 2\|x_n - x_0\|^2 - 4\left\|\frac{x_m + x_n}{2} - x_0\right\|^2.$$
Note that $\frac{x_m + x_n}{2} \in V$, so
$$\left\|\frac{x_m + x_n}{2} - x_0\right\|^2 \ge r^2,$$
by definition of $r$. Therefore,
$$\|x_m - x_n\|^2 < 2\left(r^2 + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}\right) + 2\left(r^2 + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}\right) - 4r^2 = \varepsilon.$$

Thus, $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. It has a limit $x_\infty$, by completeness. I claim that $x_\infty - x_0 \in V^\perp \setminus \{0\}$.

First,
\begin{align*}
\|x_\infty - x_0\| &= \left\|\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n - x_0\right\| \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n - x_0\| \\
&= r > 0,
\end{align*}
so $x_\infty - x_0 \neq 0$.

To see that $x_\infty - x_0 \in V^\perp$, fix $v \in V \setminus \{0\}$, and suppose $t \in \Bbb{C}$ (or just $\Bbb{R}$, if we're in the reals) to be decided shortly. Then $x_\infty + tv \in V$, so
$$\|x_\infty + tv - x_0\| \ge r = \|x_\infty - x_0\|.$$
Then
\begin{align*}
0 &\le \|x_\infty - x_0 + tv\|^2 - \|x_\infty - x_0\|^2 \\
&= |t|^2\|v\|^2 - 2\operatorname{Re}(t \langle x_\infty - x_0, v \rangle).
\end{align*}
In particular, let
$$t = \frac{\langle v, x_\infty - x_0\rangle}{\|v\|^2},$$
so that the above becomes:
$$0 \le -\frac{|\langle x_\infty - x_0, v\rangle|^2}{\|v\|^2},$$
which implies $\langle v, x_\infty - x_0\rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V \setminus \{0\}$ (and hence all $v \in V$). Thus $x_\infty - x_0 \in V^\perp$.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! The only things from Hilbert space theory that this really uses are the continuity of the norm and the parallelogram law. Thank you! May I ask, the motivation for this proof does come from orthogonal projections, right? Since $x_\infty$ would be the orthogonal projection of $x_0$?

Comment: @stowo Yes, that's right. Metric projections in Hilbert spaces are something of a specialty of mine (not just onto subspaces, or even convex sets, but onto general sets). Of course, in the subspace case, the metric projection must be an orthogonal projection too.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since $V$ is a proper subspace, there exists $w\notin V$. Let $v_i$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$. Consider $w^* = w - \sum_i \langle w, v_i\rangle v_i$. Because $w\notin V$, $w^* \ne 0$. However, $\langle w^*, v_i\rangle = 0$ for all $v_i$. Therefore $w^*$ is an element of $V^\perp$.

(This proof may need a slight modification if $V$ is infinite dimensional and separable, but the same idea should apply. I have no idea if it would work for $V$ inseparable, but no one cares about inseparable Hilbert spaces anyways.)

Comment: Personally, I would be cautious about assuming $V$ has an orthonormal basis. How would you prove this without assuming Theorem 1 is true? A Zorn's lemma argument could find an orthonormal set from $V$ with maximal closed span, but to conclude that this closed span is $V$ would require applying Theorem 1 to the closed span of this set. Or perhaps, you have a better method?

Comment: This is a neat, slick proof for the case $V$ is finite-dimensional! Although, I am interested in proofs that work when $V$ is infinite-dimensional and even not necessarily separable. Theorem 2 and 3 do not make such assumptions about dimension or separability. However, maybe this hints that all simpler proofs of Theorem 1 must rely on further assumptions like finite-dimensionality